# How can I determine which version of virtualenvwrapper is installed?

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I know that `which virtualenvwrapper.sh` will locate the virtualenvwrapper bash script.

But, how can I determine which version of virtualenvwrapper is installed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Updated Answer 02-Jun-17

Using [pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip):

```
$ pip list | grep virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper (4.7.2)
```

## Original Answer

Not an elegant solution, but here's how I determined that I have version 2.10.1 of virtualenvwrapper installed:

```
$ which virtualenvwrapper.sh
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
$ cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
$ ls virtualenvwrapper*
virtualenvwrapper-2.10.1-py2.7-nspkg.pth
virtualenvwrapper-2.10-1-py2.7.egg-info
```